# Why does my program crash upon writing to a file?

Tags: c, file, debugging, crash, runtime-error

I know I really shouldn't ask for bug solutions here in Stack exchange, but  I'm new to C and I made a program that unrolls code and prints the code out in a .c file. The problem is that when I want to print out some lines of code, the `fputs` function to codeOutput crashes the program(I've debugged it this far). I've tried changing the codeOutput file from .c to .txt, but it hasn't changed anything. I know this code excerpt is not really repeatable, but I'm sure I just made a dumb mistake in writing the code. heres my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main()
{
    char buf[500];

    int numberOfSamples = 5;
    int numberOfElements = 10;
    int currentTest = 1;

    FILE *arrayAssignmentReader[numberOfSamples];
    FILE *codeSnippetReader[numberOfSamples];
    FILE *arrayPrintReader[numberOfSamples];
    FILE *codeOutput[numberOfSamples];

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSamples; i++) {
        sprintf(buf, "C:/Users/Erlandas/Desktop/Research/C/TestNo%i/ProgramNo1/SampleNo%i/ArrayAssignment.txt", currentTest, i);
        arrayAssignmentReader[i] = fopen(buf, "r+");
        sprintf(buf, "C:/Users/Erlandas/Desktop/Research/C/TestNo%i/ProgramNo2/SampleNo%i/codeSnippet.txt", currentTest, i);
        codeSnippetReader[i] = fopen(buf, "r+");
        sprintf(buf, "C:/Users/Erlandas/Desktop/Research/C/TestNo%i/ProgramNo1/SampleNo%i/ProgramNo1PrintArray.txt", currentTest, i);
        arrayPrintReader[i] = fopen(buf, "r+");

        sprintf(buf, "C:/Users/Erlandas/Desktop/Research/C/TestNo%i/codeForNo3/codeNo%i/", currentTest, i);
        struct stat st = {0};
        if (stat(buf, &st) == -1) {
            mkdir(buf);
        }

        sprintf(buf, "C:/Users/Erlandas/Desktop/Research/C/TestNo%i/codeForNo3/CodeNo%i/CodeNo%i.c", currentTest, i, i);
        codeOutput[i] = fopen(buf, "w+");
    }

    for (int currentSample = 0; currentSample < numberOfSamples; currentSample++) {

        sprintf(buf, "#include <stdio.h>\n#include <time.h>\n#include <stdlib.h>\n#include <sys/types.h>\n#include <sys/stat.h>\n#include <math.h>\n#include <unistd.h>\n#define BILLION  1000000000L\nint main()\n{\nchar buf[500];\nint numberOfElements = %i;\nint currentTest = %i;\nint randomArray[numberOfElements];\nint minIndex;\nint minValue;\nstruct timespec requestStart;\nstruct timespec requestEnd;\nlong int recordStartTime;\nlong int recordEndTime;\nlong int elapsedTime;\nFILE *arrangedArray;\nFILE *stopwatch;\nsprintf(buf,\"C:/Users/Erlandas/Desktop/Research/C/TestNo%%i/ProgramNo3/ProgramNo3Stopwatch.txt\", currentTest);\nstopwatch = fopen(buf, \"a+\");\nstruct stat st = {0};\nsprintf(buf, \"C:/Users/Erlandas/Desktop/Research/C/TestNo%%i/ProgramNo3/\", currentTest);\nif (stat(buf, &st) == -1)\n{\nsprintf(buf, \"C:/Users/Erlandas/Desktop/Research/C/TestNo%%i/ProgramNo3/\", currentTest);\nmkdir(buf);\n}\nsprintf(buf, \"C:/Users/Erlandas/Desktop/Research/C/TestNo%%i/CodeForNo3/SampleNo%i/ArrangedArray.txt\", currentTest, currentSample);\narrangedArray = fopen(buf, \"w+\");\n", numberOfElements, currentTest, currentSample);
        fputs(buf, codeOutput[currentSample]);

        while (buf[0] != EOF){
            fgets(buf, 500, arrayAssignmentReader[currentSample]);
            fputs(buf, codeOutput[currAentSample]);
            fputs("\n", codeOutput[currentSample]);
        }

        sprintf(buf, "clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &requestStart);\nrecordStartTime = requestStart.tv_nsec + requestStart.tv_sec * BILLION;\n");
        fputs(buf, codeOutput[currentSample]);

        while (buf[0] != EOF) {
            fgets(buf, 500, codeSnippetReader[currentSample]);
            fputs(buf, codeOutput[currentSample]);
            fputs("\n", codeOutput[currentSample]);
        }

        sprintf(buf, "clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &requestEnd);\nrecordEndTime = (requestEnd.tv_nsec + requestEnd.tv_sec * BILLION);\nelapsedTime = recordEndTime - recordStartTime;\nsprintf(buf, \"%%li\\n\", elapsedTime);\nfputs(buf, stopwatch);\n");
        fputs(buf, codeOutput[currentSample]);

        while (buf[0] != EOF) {
            fgets(buf, 500, arrayPrintReader[currentSample]);
            fputs(buf, codeOutput[currentSample]);
            fputs("\n", codeOutput[currentSample]);
        }

        sprintf(buf, "\nfclose(output);\nfclose(arrayOutput);\nfclose(arrangedArray);\n}\nfclose(stopwatch);\nreturn 0;\n}\n");
        fputs(buf, codeOutput[currentSample]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`buf` is not large enough for this statement:

`sprintf(buf, "#include <stdio.h>\n#include <time.h>\n#include <stdlib.h>\n#include <sys/types.h>\n#include <sys/stat.h>\n#include <math.h>\n#include <unistd.h>\n#define BILLION  1000000000L\nint main()\n{\nchar buf[500];\nint numberOfElements = %i;\nint currentTest = %i;\nint randomArray[numberOfElements];\nint minIndex;\nint minValue;\nstruct timespec requestStart;\nstruct timespec requestEnd;\nlong int recordStartTime;\nlong int recordEndTime;\nlong int elapsedTime;\nFILE *arrangedArray;\nFILE *stopwatch;\nsprintf(buf,\"C:/Users/Erlandas/Desktop/Research/C/TestNo%%i/ProgramNo3/ProgramNo3Stopwatch.txt\", currentTest);\nstopwatch = fopen(buf, \"a+\");\nstruct stat st = {0};\nsprintf(buf, \"C:/Users/Erlandas/Desktop/Research/C/TestNo%%i/ProgramNo3/\", currentTest);\nif (stat(buf, &st) == -1)\n{\nsprintf(buf, \"C:/Users/Erlandas/Desktop/Research/C/TestNo%%i/ProgramNo3/\", currentTest);\nmkdir(buf);\n}\nsprintf(buf, \"C:/Users/Erlandas/Desktop/Research/C/TestNo%%i/CodeForNo3/SampleNo%i/ArrangedArray.txt\", currentTest, currentSample);\narrangedArray = fopen(buf, \"w+\");\n", numberOfElements, currentTest, currentSample);`

You should make `buf` much larger and use `snprintf()` to avoid buffer overflows.

You should break all these strings into fragments that fit on regular lines:

```
sprintf(buf, "clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &requestEnd);\n"
             "recordEndTime = (requestEnd.tv_nsec + requestEnd.tv_sec * BILLION);\n"
             "elapsedTime = recordEndTime - recordStartTime;\n"
             "sprintf(buf, \"%%li\\n\", elapsedTime);\n"
             "fputs(buf, stopwatch);\n");
fputs(buf, codeOutput[currentSample]);
```

But note however that you do not need `sprintf()` at all for some of these: since you are not substituting any variables, so you could just call `fputs` with the string directly.

Furthermore, the way you test for end of file is incorrect: `while (buf[0] != EOF)` cannot test if you have reached the end of file, checking the return value of `fgets()` is the correct way to do this:

```
    while (fgets(buf, 500, arrayAssignmentReader[currentSample]) != NULL) {
        fputs(buf, codeOutput[currentSample]);
        fputs("\n", codeOutput[currentSample]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking the result of the fopen() function to make sure it is not NULL:

```
codeOutput[i] = fopen(buf, "w+");
if (codeOutput[i] == NULL) {
    perror(buf); /* Assuming perror is supported and you
                    #include <errno.h> */
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Just tried it out, doesn't change anything. I open the files with no problem, there's the problem of writhing to them